# Syntax error in Ruby Post Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, model, controller, syntax-error

first off, im new to ruby. I'm building a forum from scratch for fun.

Got the authorization stuff done, and can post new topics with original content, but I'm having an issue with the the posts (replies) controlller.

Here is the error i get:

```
SyntaxError in PostsController#new

/Users/mlegacy/Documents/RubyProjects/forum/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:48: syntax 
error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
```

And here is my controller code:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts = Post.order("sticky desc")
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user = current_user
  if @post.save
    redirect_to topics_url, notice: "Post created."
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to topics_url, notice: "Updated post."
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.destroy
  redirect_to topics_url, notics: "Post removed."
end

private

  def post_params
    params.require(:posts).permit(:content, :created_at, :updated_at)
  end
end
```

And my model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic
end
```

Then the topic#show view, and the posts#new view:

topic#show:

```
<h1><%= @topic.name %></h1>
<p><%= @topic.post_content %></p>

<% @topic.posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="post">
    <%= post.content %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<p><%= link_to "Post new reply", posts_new_path %></p>

<p><%= link_to "Back to topics", topics_path %></p>
```

Posts#new

```
<h1>New Post</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed "if" in the update action.

```
def update
  if @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to topics_url, notice: "Updated post."
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Comment: God, the dumb things people do...thanks for catching that bro. Knew it had to be something dumb since it was a syntax error.